# Equivalent of wget command line for windows 8.1

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-8.1, wget, git-bash

I'm using git bash as my command line interface in my working environment.

Is there a `wget` command available for windows 8.1?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use curl instead of wget.

```
curl http://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 16):

Windows 8.1 PowerShell has both the wget and the curl commands.

The both perform identically as if they are synonyms for each other.

---

Example - to retrieve http://www.sdsolarblog.com/montage/show.html

```
PS C:/users/Admin> curl http://www.sdsolarblog.com/montage/show.html
```

or

```
PS C:/users/Admin> wget http://www.sdsolarblog.com/montage/show.html
```

---

Here is what it looks like in practice:

[image]

---

### To download the entire raw file you want to add the `-outfile` option like so:

```
PS C:/users/Admin> curl http://www.sdsolarblog.com/montage/show.html -outfile show.html
```

Comment: this one is good. The top one does not tell how to save the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly download wget for windows 
1) Download wget for windows from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm or https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ 
2) Download install cygwin from cygwin.com and install the wget package 
3) Get similar tools like curl for windows from curl.haxx.se

Answer (score 0):

Use CygWin and download the package for wGet

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fwget%2Fwget-1.16.3-1&grep=wget